# find all linked rows in table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table:

```
| id       | user_id  | phone_number |    email        |
| -------- | -------- | ------------ | --------------- |
| 1        | 999      | 61412308310  |can@gmail.com    |
| 2        | 129      | 61477708777  |acdc@gmail.com   | 
| 3        | 213      | 61488908495  |adel99@gmail.com |
| 4        | 145      | 61477708777  |austr@gmail.com  | 
| 5        | 214      | 61421445777  |austr@gmail.com  |
| 6        | 214      | 61421445326  |jango@gmail.com  |
```

It takes any value in columns (user_id, phone_number, email) from the dataset as input and should look for an intersection in all rows.

For example:

phone_number = 61477708777

result should be:

```
| id       | user_id  | phone_number | email           |
| -------- | -------- | ------------ | --------------- |
| 2        | 129      | 61477708777  |acdc@gmail.com   | 
| 4        | 145      | 61477708777  |austr@gmail.com  | 
| 5        | 214      | 61421445777  |austr@gmail.com  |
| 6        | 214      | 61421445326  |jango@gmail.com  |
```

id = 2 and id = 4 match the search terms (phone_number = 61477708777).
id = 5 has the same email with row id 4, id=6 has the same user_id  with id=5.

Im write function:

```
def search_data(field, value, data):
    data_dict = {}
    for row in data:
        key = row[field]
        if key not in data_dict:
            data_dict[key] = []
        data_dict[key].append(row)
    return data_dict.get(value, [])
```

It finds values ​​only by the field that matches in the condition, but it still needs to find related rows.

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Get the list of `user_id` where phone = "your value". Filter the data for those `user_id`.

Comment: if I do a selection by the phone column and the value 61477708777 then the first 2 rows will be: 2, 129, 61477708777, 'acdc@gmail.com ' 4, 145, 61477708777, 'austr@gmail.com' select key , id , phone , email from us where phone = '61477708777' since id= 4 has the same email with id= 5, you need to add line with id 5 to it as well since id= 5 has the same user_id with id= 6, you need to add line 6 in result query as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, to test I started from a dictionary list to make the rows like this:

```
data = [
    {"id": 1, "user_id": 999, "phone_number": "61412308310", "email": "can@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 2, "user_id": 129, "phone_number": "61477708777", "email": "acdc@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 3, "user_id": 213, "phone_number": "61488908495", "email": "adel99@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 4, "user_id": 145, "phone_number": "61477708777", "email": "austr@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 5, "user_id": 214, "phone_number": "61421445777", "email": "austr@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 6, "user_id": 214, "phone_number": "61421445326", "email": "jango@gmail.com"},
]
```

And so with that I have the following code:

```
def search_data(field, value, data):
    # List who contain row to verify
    row_list = []
    # List who contain id of row to avoid duplicate
    id_list = []

    # Search inital field, value pair
    for row in data:
        field_value = row[field]
        if field_value == value:
            row_list.append(row)
            id_list.append(row["id"])

    while len(row_list) > 0:
        actual_row = row_list.pop(0)

        for row in data:
            # Verify if this has not already been added to row_list before
            if row["id"] in id_list:
                continue

            # Iter through the keys to find a match
            for key in row:
                if actual_row[key] == row[key]:
                    row_list.append(row)
                    id_list.append(row["id"])
                    break

    print(id_list)
```

And I get: `[2, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: the function works, but the computational complexity is high. Thanks.